# How can we reboot through keyboard port

Tags: c, linux, io, x86, osdev

How is the below code able to reboot the system, can any provide documentation on this

```
#define KEYBOARD_PORT 0x64
ioperm(KEYBOARD_PORT, 0x01, 0x01);
outb(0xfe, KEYBOARD_PORT);
```

What is the significance of writing '0xfe' on the Keyboard Port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original 8042 "PS/2 keyboard controller" design had some extra pins on the controller and the cheapskate IBM engineers did wire lots of stuff to these extra pins. One pin was wired to the CPU reset pin, another unused pin was used to fix the 80286 address wraparound incompatibility, the fix was called the [the A20 gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A20_line#A20_gate).

The command byte `0xFx` means "pulse the chosen line down for 6 milliseconds", with `E` choosing the reset line (the bit 0 is zeroed). The effect is resetting the CPU so that it starts executing code according to its boot sequence.

Naturally the current PCs do not have Intel 8042 microcontrollers, just an emulation thereof...

---

More information in Osdev wiki articles [Reboot](https://wiki.osdev.org/Reboot) and [PS/2 Controller](https://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller).